# Applying formula to conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I use an Excel table to store concentrations of substances. If the concentration is less than the limit, a value of "ND" or "LOD" is logged to the Excel table.

For further use, I want the cells with values "ND" and "LOD" to show "<[limit]" without affecting the actual value in the cell ("ND" or "LOD"), and without adding additional columns/cells to the Excel.

###### How the table looks like:

|  | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| Limit | 5 |
|  | 25 |
|  | ND |
|  | 18 |
|  | LOD |

###### How the table should look like:

|  | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| Limit | 5 |
|  | 25 |
|  | <5 |
|  | 18 |
|  | <5 |

I have succesfully gotten the formula `=IF(OR(B3="ND";B3="LOD");"<"&B2;B3)` to work in a a different cell. I have unsuccessfully tried to apply the same formula to conditional formatting.

How to achieve the wanted result in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is fine, but just need the 'OR' part of it:

```
=OR(B3="ND";B3="LOD")
```

Then try a custom format of

```
;;;"<5"
```

in conditional formatting.